# How to Check it is list or list of list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists below

```
 list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
 list2 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```

Now I have to find

```
Is list1 is list of list
Expected result "False"

Is list2 is list of list
Expected result is "True"
```

How to achieve this

Comment: Do heterogenous lists count as lists of lists if any of the elements are lists?  For example, what should `[[1,2,3], 1,2,3]` return?

Comment: @user3483203, True I am expected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to know if anything in the list is a list:

```
any(isinstance(a, list) for a in list1)
```

If you want to know if all the things in the list are lists:

```
all(isinstance(a, list) for a in list1)
```

This takes advantage of passing a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to `all()`.

Comment: you can even avoid the double parentheses: `any(isinstance(a, list) for a in list1)`
It does stop calculation as soon as it finds a True.
And it is more readable

Answer (score -4):

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]

print(type(list1[0]))
print(type(list2[0]))

Output:
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
```